# Modifying local file inside Android

Tags: android

I have an XML file stored in the res/xml that I am trying to write to. I know how to read it using XmlResourceParser, but I have not been able to find a way to write to that file locally.

Thanks 
Venkat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify the resources. They are compiled at apk build time.

The only thing you can do is to store the file to another location(ds-card or internal memory), modify it here and use that newly created file.

Comment: why is (-1) here? any comments?

Comment: Thanks Ivanov... Have u had any example related your answer